# Counting letters numbers and punctuation in a string

Tags: python

How can I write a program that counts letters, numbers and punctuation(separately) in a string?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show that you have put some effort into trying to answer this question yourself.

Comment: What do you mean by "separately"?

Answer (score 8):

For a slightly more condensed / faster version, there is also

count = lambda l1,l2: sum([1 for x in l1 if x in l2])

so for example:

```
count = lambda l1,l2: sum([1 for x in l1 if x in l2])

In [11]: s = 'abcd!!!'

In [12]: count(s,set(string.punctuation))                                                                                                      
Out[12]: 3
```

using a set should get you a speed boost somewhat.

also depending on the size of the string I think you should get a memory benefit over the filter as well.

Comment: I like this solution better.  The top answer is a little more muddled by lambdas.

Comment: You don't need a list comprehension here, a plain generator expression is not only shorter but also more efficient.

Comment: but not faster.  generators are slower because they ... generate. hence why i said faster

Comment: even more concisely you could generate a regex for punctuation/numbers/letters - it would be faster than anything else here (depending on how they implemented the regex)

Answer (score 4):

```
import string
a = "I'm not gonna post my homework as question on OS again, I'm not gonna..."

count = lambda l1, l2: len(list(filter(lambda c: c in l2, l1)))

a_chars =  count(a, string.ascii_letters)
a_punct = count(a, string.punctuation)
```

Comment: `sum` should be `len` I think. And also, there is parenthesis mismatch.

Comment: you're right, i wrote in about 10 seconds 'cause i was in a hurry, fixed =P

Comment: Also a note, in Python 3+, filter returns a filter object and it doesn't support len. Maybe `list(filter(...))` is a better for compatibility.

Comment: @utdemir nice to know, I'm still too lazy to install and use Py3 but i know i have to ^^'

Answer (score 2):

```
count_chars = ".arPZ"
string = "Phillip S. is doing a really good job."
counts = tuple(string.count(c) for c in count_chars)

print counts
```

> (2, 2, 1, 1, 0)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import string
>>> import operator
>>> import functools
>>> a = "This, is an example string. 42 is the best number!"
>>> letters = string.ascii_letters
>>> digits = string.digits
>>> punctuation = string.punctuation
>>> letter_count = len(filter(functools.partial(operator.contains, letters), a))
>>> letter_count
36
>>> digit_count = len(filter(functools.partial(operator.contains, digits), a))
>>> digit_count
2
>>> punctuation_count = len(filter(functools.partial(operator.contains, punctuation), a))
>>> punctuation_count
3
```

http://docs.python.org/library/string.html

http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.contains

http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#len

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter

Answer (score 0):

To loop over a string you can use a for-loop:

```
for c in "this is a test string with punctuation ,.;!":
    print c
```

outputs:

```
t
h
i
s
...
```

Now, all you have to do is count the occurrences...

Comment: a = "I'm not gonna post my homework as question on OS again."